# Page goes blank while inserting data into database using codeigniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am inserting data into the database and while it is inserting the page goes blank and then returns.

Here is my code:

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('post_image'))
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('post_message', $this->upload->display_errors());
    $this->session->set_flashdata('post_message_class', 'alert-danger');
    redirect('/user/profile/'.$identity, 'refresh');
}
else
{
    $uploaded = $this->upload->data();
    $post_text = "";                        
    // insert pos
    if(isset($uploaded['file_name']) && $uploaded['file_name'] == 0)
    {                       
        $post_text = '<img src="/uploads/images/'.$uploaded['file_name'].'" width="251px" alt="'.$uploaded['raw_name'].'" /><br>'.$this->input->post('post_text');                                  
    }
    else 
    {
        foreach ($uploaded as $images)
        {                                               
            $post_text .= '<img src="/uploads/images/'.$images['file_name'].'" width="251px" alt="'.$images['raw_name'].'" />';                                                 
        }
        $post_text .= $this->input->post('post_text');  
    }               

    $query = $this->user_model->insert_user_posts($this->input->post('poster_id'), $this->input->post('profile_id'), $this->input->post('post_type'), $post_text);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('post_message', 'Image has been posted!');
    $this->session->set_flashdata('post_message_class', 'alert-success');
    redirect('/user/profile/'.$identity, 'refresh');          
}
```

Here is the code to the model:

```
public function insert_user_posts($poster_id, $profile_id, $post_type, $post_text)
{
    // Users table.
    $data = array(
        'poster_id'     => $poster_id,
        'profile_id'    => $profile_id,
        'post_type'     => $post_type,
        'post_text'     => $post_text,
        'datetime'      => time()
    );

    $this->db->insert($this->tables['users_posts'], $data);

    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
    {
        $this->set_message('upload_successful');
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;   
    }
}
```

Also, I am using this: https://github.com/avenirer/MY_Upload

Is there a way to do this without the paging showing blank while inserting into the database?

Comment: Have you followed CI3 naming conventions??

Comment: Yes, I don't believe I did anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and use exit to track where exactly is the error.

Comment: I should probably be more clear in my question, but I am not receiving an error. The page goes blank, inserts data into database, and then returns back to the existing page. I added caching and this seemed to reduce the  time the blank page shows.

Comment: This is to be expected because you are using `redirect()` which means the page has to reload and it takes time to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: put the upload code in a model (or a library), call it from a user controller method, then show the upload error or the newly updated profile. then you don't have to redirect or create a bunch of flash session messages.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to figure this out, but if I add it to a library or model why do I not have to redirect? Also, if I wanted to show success message wouldn't I need to set flash data?

Comment: Rather than redirecting, using ajax might be one way to handle this. Messages would be returned via the ajax response and dynamically (via javascript) displayed on the page.